# issue with invoking blackberry sms and email application

Tags: email, blackberry, sms

To invoke blackberry SMS application,i have used this code

```java
MessageConnection mc = null;
try {
    mc = (MessageConnection)Connector.open( "sms://" );
    mc.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
TextMessage m = (TextMessage)mc.newMessage( MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE );
m.setAddress( "sms://984" );
m.setPayloadText("SMS content");
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, new MessageArguments(m));
```

Problem is i am able to invoke the `SMS` application. **Issue was,**By default in blackberry SMS application I am able to see two `to` options.**

I referred this also

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Create_new_populated_text_msg_565424_11.jsp

Can anyone tell where i am doing the mistake?
For invoking email application i have used this code.

```java
MessageArguments msgArgs = new MessageArguments(MessageArguments.ARG_NEW, 
                                                "a@gmail.com", 
                                                "h", 
                                                "hai");
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, msgArgs);
```

for this also i am getting same problem. Invoking the email application but the application has **two** **To`** options.

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: by default it give two tos one is for single person and another one for Bcc

Comment: but it showing the label as To only not Bcc.is it like that only?

Comment: for sms application also  why it showing two To's?and nomally if we open the message or mail app there is only one To option.